# how can I receive all message by libevent

Tags: c++, networking, server, libevent

Currently, I use `libevent` to send and receive messages. The issue I am currently encountering is that I do not receive all messages on the server; and only receive the first message I sent.

Client Code:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    bufferevent_write(bev, data, strlen(data) + 1);
}
```

Server Code:

```
static void read_cb(struct bufferevent* bev, void* arg)
{
        char buf[2048] = {};
        bufferevent_read(bev, buf, sizeof(buf));
        //do something

}
```

I have modified the client like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    bufferevent_write(bev, data, strlen(data) + 1);
    sleep(1)
}
```

When I add a `sleep(1)`,I can receive all messages.

I would like to avoid using `sleep(1)`. What needs to be added / changed in code, such that all messages can be received, and `sleep` is not used.

Comment: C and C++ tags are mutually exclusive, please fix that. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Not familiar with this library, but you should check the return value from `bufferevent_write` to see if it's trying to send you a message like, "Slow the <expletive deleted> down! I'm <expletive deleted>ing full!"

Comment: I add the debug info ,bufferevent_write return the same value `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation seems to be a bit like a spacket splicing problem, you can try this

```
   static void read_cb(struct bufferevent* bev, void* arg)
   {
       char bufs[2048];
       struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
       size_t lens = evbuffer_get_length(input);

       char * rline = bufs;
       while( lens > 0){
           char buf [1024]
           memcpy(buf, rline, strlen(data));  
           rline = rline + strlen(data);
           lens = lens -strlen(data);
           // use buf do something else
        }
   }
```